# Why can I not get end notes in my latex file

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage[notes,endnotes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{Stuff}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Introduction}  
Bla Bla bla \autocite{cite1}

\newpage
\printendnotes
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For some reason this continues to print everything out as foot notes instead of end notes.  I've tried changing \autocite to \endcite but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of syntax errors:

- the `\begin{multicols}{2}` must be closed at one point (or removed altogether)
- `\printendnotes` is a macro from the `enotez` package, not from endnotes. Your .log file will tell you that the macro is not defined. You shouldn't simply ignore such errors
- your .log will also tell you about the non-existing package options you try to use. Don't ignore such errors!

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage[notetype=endonly]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\title{Stuff}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
%    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Introduction}  
Bla Bla bla \autocite{knuth:ct}

\newpage
\theendnotes
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]